# how to use multiple negroni.Wrap()

Tags: go

I have an issue to implement middleware i want to use `negroni.Wrap` function for validate user location and one for calling handler below is my route:

```
r.Handle("/users/{userID}", negroni.New(
        negroni.HandlerFunc(validateTokenMiddleware),
        negroni.Wrap(&userLocation),
        negroni.Wrap(&userDetailHandler),
    )).Methods("GET")
```

and `&userLocation` is object of an struct which contain db information, here when i request for handler then that time both `wrap` execute together. But i want execute `&userlocation` first and if any errors occur so `next wrap` should not be execute , how to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use Wrap call your middleware directly which contains (next(res, req)). So If error comes dont run next middleware

Answer (score 0):

Use a middleware having ServeHttp Method which will be called using userDetailHandler as receiver inside middleware. And pass your db struct in middleware as an argument . You should use single wrap.

```
r.Handle("/users/{userID}", negroni.New(
        negroni.HandlerFunc(validateTokenMiddleware),
        negroni.Wrap(userDetailHandler.Middleware(&userLocation)),
    )).Methods("GET")

func (userDetailHandler *UserDetailHandler)Middleware(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, userLocation *userLocation){
   // use your serve Http inside this
   userDetailHandler.ServeHttp(res, req)
}
```